# AJAX and MYSQL, AJAX too fast for mysql to query?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am working on a php/mysql application, I am trying to collect javascript errors to the database using window.onerror, where inside that function I make an ajax request to a php script that will log the errors into the database. However, when I tested it there are supposed to be 13 errors logged, but only one get inserted into the database. All the 13 ajax requests return 200 OK, is this happening because ajax is just simply too fast for the mysql query to process anything. I tried using set timeout on the send request but it doesnt seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line)
{

function createXHR()
{
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch(e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0"); } catch (e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); } catch (e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}

    return null;
}

function sendRequest(url, payload)
{
    var xhr = createXHR();
    if (xhr)
    {
        xhr.open("POST",url,true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (xhr.readyState == 4  && xhr.status == 200){
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };
        xhr.send(payload);
    }

}

function encodeValue(val)
{
    var encodedVal;
    if (!encodeURIComponent)
    {
        encodedVal = escape(val);
        /* fix the omissions */
        encodedVal = encodedVal.replace(/@/g, '%40');
        encodedVal = encodedVal.replace(/\//g, '%2F');
        encodedVal = encodedVal.replace(/\+/g, '%2B');
    }
    else
    {
        encodedVal = encodeURIComponent(val);
        /* fix the omissions */
        encodedVal = encodedVal.replace(/~/g, '%7E');
        encodedVal = encodedVal.replace(/!/g, '%21');
        encodedVal = encodedVal.replace(/\(/g, '%28');
        encodedVal = encodedVal.replace(/\)/g, '%29');
        encodedVal = encodedVal.replace(/'/g, '%27');
    }
    /* clean up the spaces and return */
    return encodedVal.replace(/\%20/g,'+');
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

    var master = "llesmana@ucsd.edu";

    var payload = "msg=" + encodeValue(msg) + '&url=' + encodeValue(url) + "&line=" + encodeValue(line) + "&master=" + encodeValue(master);
    var url_req = "http://104.131.199.129:83/php/log_error.php";
    sendRequest(url_req, payload);
    return true;
}

return false;

}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: xxvii27
 * Date: 9/2/14
 * Time: 12:30 PM
 */


/* Helper functions */
function gpc($name)
{
    if (isset($_GET[$name]))
        return $_GET[$name];
    else if (isset($_POST[$name]))
        return $_POST[$name];
    else if (isset($_COOKIE[$name]))
        return $_COOKIE[$name];
    else
        return "";
}

//Database Connection
function connectDB (){
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_NAME', 'userinfo');
    define('DB_USER','root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD','ohanajumba');

    $con=mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error() );

    return $con;
}


function logError($occured, $name, $line, $master, $url, $db){

    $command="INSERT INTO errors (id, occured, name, url, line, master) VALUES (NULL, '$occured', '$name', '$url','$line', '$master')";
    mysqli_query($db, $command) or die(mysql_error());
}


$db = connectDB();

$message = htmlentities(substr(urldecode(gpc("msg")),0,1024));
$url = htmlentities(substr(urldecode(gpc("url")),0,1024));
$line = htmlentities(substr(urldecode(gpc("line")),0,1024));
$master = htmlentities(substr(urldecode(gpc("master")),0,1024));

$date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', time());

logError($date, $message, $line, $master, $url, $db);


mysqli_close($db);
```

Also, I have checked all the sent data through the request and all of them have been received properly by the script, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Change `mysql_error()` to `mysqli_error($db)`.

Comment: `AJAX` is asynchronous, which means it can't be "too fast". depends on how your `Javascript` code looks like, but if you coded it properly, each `AJAX`-request is send to the server on it's own, using it's own "instance" of `PHP` code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it , apparently I forgot to use mysqli_real_escape_string().